# file/folder explorer in react application

Tags: list-item, react, fluent-ui, file-explorer

I have a SharePoint application in react fluent ui. I would like to know if there is a way to build a folder explorer.

The application manges a SharePoint list. For each list item I would like to let user select a folder in the SharePoint site contents, and, optionally, to visualise its contents.

I already [asked the question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76164895/sample-folder-explorer-in-a-sharepoint-react-application), with some code as sample, but any answer till now, so I ask here maybe someone.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the source code from the [PnP Reusable Controls File Picker](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/tree/master/src/controls/filePicker)